# Google Apps Script: Too many simultaneous invocations

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, gs-installable-triggers

I have a trigger set on my sheet that is set to run when my associated form is submitted. Weirdly, this seems to have worked once, but all other times I have got this failure summary via email:

Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets (line 20, file "Code")

The line in question is:

```
var rData = sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).getValues();
```

In context, this is what I'm doing:

```
 function addSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var rData = sh.getRange(row, 1, 1, 3).getValues();

  if (row == 1) {
    ss.toast("The are the column titles, you can not send these.");    
    return
  }

  if(rData[0][0] != null || rData[0][1] != null || rData[0][2] != null) {
    try {      

      //set active spreadsheet to template
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("TEMPLATESHEETKEY");

      // Create new sheet with a copy of template and name it with the row number, space, and event name
      var newSS = ss.copy(+(row)+' '+rData[0][1]);


      // Move to original folder
      var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("MYFOLDERKEY");
      var newSSFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSS.getId());
      targetFolder.addFile(newSSFile);
      DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(newSSFile);     



      //target title space and set it as the name/first cell
      newSS.getRange("D8").setValue('=importrange("MYSHEETKEY","eventlist!B'+(row)+'")');


      //target date space and set it as the date
      newSS.getRange("D11").setValue('=importrange("MYSHEETKEY","eventlist!C'+(row)+'")');



    } catch(e) {
      throw 'Something has gone wrong...';      
    }
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any advice...

UPDATE - This started to work consistently for a little while, although I have changed nothing. I'm wondering if this has got anything to do with the limitations of quotas? It has since stopped working again!

Comment: [Form submit triggers have been flaky](https://plus.google.com/+EricKoleda/posts/Abh4Gnpaedc), and may continue to be so.